# Tensorflow difference of learning loops

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensor flow and I see 2 different ways to use the `GradientDescentOptimiser`:

```
for (x, y) in zip(trX, trY):
   sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
```

I see also this kind of integrated loop

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX, Y: trY})
```

I tested both but get slightly different results. For the time being I just train myself on an easy linear regression but it may have an impact on `ANN`. Why is there a difference and which is the best code for neural networks?

Comment: Hi JLB, can you give more code about the second case ? What is train_op, variables X and Y ?

Comment: Sure, here below there is more code with the definition of cost, gradientDescent.
The only difference is really about the loop on the estimation as mentioned here above.

cost = tf.square(Y - y_model) # use square error for cost function
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)
var_grad = tf.gradients(cost,w)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    for i in range(100):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX, Y: trY})

Comment: You probably want the latter -- get tensorflow to drive the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient descent is an iterative process which minimize a cost function by updating parameters a lot of time with :

*W' = W - a  delta_W*

where *W* is the set of parameters of your model, *a* the learning rate and *delta_W* is an approximation of the gradient of the cost function. (see more details [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/OptimizationStochasticGradientDescent/))

`sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X:...,Y:...})` compute only one iteration using X and Y to approximate the gradient.

So your second code approximate the gradient using all the training dataset (it's expensive but the approximation is accurate) and apply only **one** update. It's not enough to convergence to a minimum.

Your first code is better, you apply one update par example, but the approximation is not very accurate (because you use only one example).

I suggest you to create a function `generate_mini_batch` which return a random set of data on your training dataset with their associated labels and run this loop :

```
for i in range(N_STEPS) : # with N_STEPS very large
      batch_x,batch_y = generate_mini_batch(trX,trY,s) # s is th size of the mini-batch
      sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
```

This method is called Mini-batch Gradient Descent (see this [video](https://fr.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/9zJUs/mini-batch-gradient-descent)) and it's actually widely used for optimization problem.

Comment: Got it. I am surprised that the solution is so similar using a gradient estimated for each point compared to the full dataset. The minibatch indeed is a classical solution that seems optimal. Thanks !